# How urgent is it to replace a leaking fish tank?

Tags: fish, safety

It Looked like a quality fish tank. I bought it new in box from walmart. Worked great for 45 days or so and now I see water coming out at bottom of front panel at seam.

It is losing about 5 drops of water per hour.

Is this an emergency or should I just pick up a new one next weekend?

Answer (score 2):

Not an emergency, but it's likely the leak will get worse over time.

Pick up a new one next weekend. Remember to cycle your tank, and once you have everything transferred, return the defective one. Walmart is quite good about honoring defective returns and all that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest replacing or repairing as soon as possible.

There is a danger that the leak will grow. 5 drops per hour sounds quite big speed. This is a positive feedback: the larger leak is, the larger pressure on the tank and the larger leak will be. You risk this can happen when you are not at home or at night.

The pressure of water being above the leak is the pressure causing the defect. You say it is at bottom, so the leak is under pressure of almost all water.

Also, if the tank is standing on a wooden cabinet, water can make wood wet and deform it, without possibility to repair.

As rlb.usa has written, buy a new tank and use the water from the broken one, so you will move all necessary bacteria to the new tank. If possible, take also the filter you already have to the new tank.